# What is the function to extract a string from column and place it inside a string of other column?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have Joomla 3.8 website with articles. I prepared 120 articles from a spreadsheet. They have all similar structured as they are youtube video embed.

I need now to insert intro image in order to get thumbnail of my articles in Xblog layout.

This can be done on each Edition page of article in backend. But it takes Joomla a lot of time to open popup, load folders and images, select image, insert.

I would prefer to make some kind of automatic copy paste in Mysql com_content tables.

I have in column introtext the image filename as I use a plugin for social tags. Have a look at screenshot when I run this search:
[a busy cat http://prntscr.com/nfnmwn](http://prntscr.com/nfnmwn)

I run this code to get this view:

```
SELECT title, introtext, images 
FROM `nfojm_content`
WHERE `images` = '{\"image_intro\":\"images\\/Acquisition\\/Scalez_votre_acquisition_de_nouveaux_utilisateurs_16-9.jpg\",\"float_intro\":\"\",\"image_intro_alt\":\"\",\"image_intro_caption\":\"\",\"image_fulltext\":\"\",\"float_fulltext\":\"\",\"image_fulltext_alt\":\"\",\"image_fulltext_caption\":\"\"}' 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

So my idea was to run an SA

I found this code here in stackoverflow, but I have no ide and to find and replace.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MESSAGE,
       CHARINDEX('*', message)+1,
                 CHARINDEX('#', message)-CHARINDEX('*', message)-1
                ) as Duration 
FROM LOGS
```

Can someone give me some help to built this SQL request?

It should looks like this:

```
For each ROW from com_content TABLE WHERE "images" LIKE "images\/Acquisition\/Scalez_votre_acquisition_de_nouveaux_utilisateurs_16-9.jpg"

EXTRACT image from column "introtext" in $tmp
$tmp = images\ & $tmp
REPLACE wrong image with $tmp in colum "images" images\/Acquisition\/Scalez_votre_acquisition_de_nouveaux_utilisateurs_16-9.jpg
```

someone has any idea?

Comment: You cound try using the JSON functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: I'm confused.  The question is tagged "mysql" but the code sample is SQL Server.  You need to tag the question correctly.

Comment: Sorry for this misunderstanding. The first code is from Mysql. The 2nd code is from a blog post I found in the internet. The 3rd code is some kind of algoritm draft in order to express what I need.